# Converting Enzyme to RTL (.instance().addNewLink())

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I know Enzyme and RTL is not a 1:1 conversion which is giving me some trouble as Im still quite new to RTL and how it differs from enzyme. Im trying to convert this test

```
it('should renders with the correct number of editing forms', () => {
    const result = shallow(<ELiteratureDocuments currentDocuments={[]} currentDocumentsSortingOrder={[]} />);
    result.instance().addNewLink();
    expect(result.find(LinkForm).length).toEqual(1);
  });
```

So I know it should look something like

```
it('should renders with the correct number of editing forms', () => {
    //RTL
    render(<ELiteratureDocuments currentDocuments={[]} currentDocumentsSortingOrder={[]} />);
    //ENZYME
    result.instance().addNewLink();
    expect(result.find(LinkForm).length).toEqual(1);
  });
```

but Im not sure how to convert the following two bottom lines to RTL.

"If your test uses `instance()` or `state()`, know that you're testing things that the user couldn't possibly know about or even care about, which will take your tests further from giving you confidence that things will work when your user uses them." — Kent C. Dodds
But Im just checking to see if things render properly when the editing forms are correct number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **getByTestId** to the element that contains the **LinkForm** then use **querySelectorAll** to get all **LinkForm** elements:

```
it('should render with the correct number of editing forms', () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<ELiteratureDocuments currentDocuments={[]} currentDocumentsSortingOrder={[]} />);
  const linkFormContainer = getByTestId('link-form-container');
  const linkForms = linkFormContainer.querySelectorAll(LinkForm);
  expect(linkForms.length).toEqual(1);
});
```

But gonna need to add **data-testid** to the element that contains **LinkForm**